# How to fix USB mouse freeze in Ubuntu 10.04 or Fedora 13?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, fedora, freeze

I'm just starting out using linux and so I installed Ubuntu to a hard disk.
I noticed that after 30 minutes or so, the mouse pointer would simply stop moving while the keyboard was o.k. 
Exact same problem with Fedora as well. (The mouse works fine in Vista (it's a MS Comfort mouse 1000))

I searched and found a suggestion that I should disable the sleep settings, so I did that but no luck.

Interestingly, there is no freezing of the mouse when I use the Ubuntu Live CD - it's only the hard-disk-installed Ubuntu that's having the problem.

**Update** Found some old links from 2009 that say I should remove the "mouseemu" package. How to remove that package?

**Update** Unfortunately, that did not help - there is no mouseemu pkg installed. I tried setting kernel boot options noapic, irqpoll etc. - no luck. This is so annoying.

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with it: https://plus.google.com/116960357493251979546/posts/RZpndv4BCCD

Comment: This problem still persists with a Microsoft *Wheel Mouse Optical USB and PS/2 Compatible* on Xubuntu LTS 14.04. Even, if you no longer use Windows™, the curse of Microsoft still comes to get ya...

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ArchLinux (could be applicable for other distros too), you need to find your device ID by `lsusb` and then add it to the blacklist in USB autosuspend by editing:

> /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf

Example of the line to add:

> AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST="046d:c025"

USB autosuspend ref: [Usb Autosuspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop_Mode_Tools#USB_autosuspend)

Don't forget to restart the `laptop-mode` service afterwards, for the changes to become effective, e.g. by running `sudo systemctl restart laptop-mode.service` resp. `sudo service laptop-mode restart`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find that or any similar configuration file on Xubuntu LTS 14.04.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt Try installing this package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/utils/laptop-mode-tools Hope it helps

Comment: On debian I had to create this file on my own. Do I have to restart anything to let those changes become effective?

Comment: Ah ok, one has to restart "laptop-mode" (e.g. by running `sudo systemctl restart laptop-mode.service`). I just didn't find it because the keyboard was suspended during tab-completion ;-)

Comment: Sometimes  unplug/plug usb cable also necessary.

Comment: @Vlad: unplugging and plugging is not a permanent solution, but it works if one is lazy :)
Note: this solution would only work for systems using laptop-mode-tools as the power management service, which is the most common one. There are other alternatives such as powertop and tlp etc., which require similar configurations.

Comment: @jadelord I mean unpluging/pluging needed with BLACKLISTing too.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it might be an issue with usb autosuspend.

Try adding `usbcore.autosuspend=0` to your boot command to disable autosuspend completely (in Ubuntu 10.04 this works, not sure about Fedora - they may load usbcore as a module).

Alternatively, you may be able to disable autosuspend on a more fine-grained level by doing:

```
echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/level
```

^ this is the path on my machine, yours is probably slightly different. Currently this should be set to `auto`; setting it to `on` will disable autosuspend on that interface.

Comment: I did that change (in /boot/grub/menu.lst), and the mouse didn't freeze for about 2 hours - and then it froze again :(

Comment: This is not working after suspend. :(

Answer (score 1):

to remove package mouseemu, do:

`sudo apt-get remove mouseemu`

I don't know if that will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help - there is no mouseemu pkg installed. I tried setting kernel boot options noapic, irqpoll etc. nothing works. This is so annoying!

Comment: If the mouse really works OK when booted from the Ubuntu live CD, then it sure sounds like a bad installation.  Perhaps you could try installing the OS again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The mouse suddenly freezes and in `/var/log/messages`:

> USB disconnect, address XX

I had to reinstall **compiz**:

```
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
cd $HOME && rm -rf .compiz/ .config/compiz/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Fedora 15.

Mouse was constantly hang for couple milliseconds and then everything was ok again. 10-40 seconds and the same thing was happening again.

I stumbled on this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Touchpad_synchronization_issues
in /var/log/messages-* , I found that USB mouse was constantly found and lost.

After that I plugged my mouse in different USB and now computer is super fast and no glitches experienced so far. :)

Comment: Yeah, even plugging the mouse in and out of the same USB socket unfreezes the mouse, but a little while later it happens again.